# Excel Power Query filter with a column name comes from avariable

Tags: excel, powerquery

What i m trying to do is to filter using Advance query with a column name which comes from a named range.

i have a named range rngDate (Type Any)

and i m trying to modify the below query to

1. Get the value from the specific named range
2. Use the specific value as a column name to filter

Working query:

```
`let
    . . . 
#"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows", each [Posting Date] >= rngStart and [Posting Date] <= rngEnd)
```

in
#"Filtered Rows1"`

Modified query:

```
`let
    . . . 
#"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows", each rngDate >= rngStart and rngDate <= rngEnd)
```

in
#"Filtered Rows1"`

Any help will appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
= Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows", each Record.Field(_, rngDate) >= rngStart and Record.Field(_, rngDate) <= rngEnd)
```

Based on this [posting](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/power-query-dynamic-reference-to-a-column.951123/)